# Explicit solution for a linear drift-diffusion equation (Fokker-Planck equation) on whole space

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, linear-pde

I'm wondering if there might be an explicit solution for the following linear PDE in two space dimensions $(x_1,x_2)$ on the whole space $\mathbb{R}^2$:
$$ 
    \partial_t f = {div} \left [\left( \begin{array}{rr}
    1/4 & 0  \\ 
    0 & 1  \\
    \end{array}\right) \nabla f + \left( \begin{array}{rr}
    1/4 & -4  \\ 
    4 & 1  \\
    \end{array}\right)xf \right ],
    $$ with $x = (x_1,x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2,$ $t >0$ and $f=f(t,x_1,x_2).$ For this equation it is known that there is sufficient regular and positive, unique solution if we impose a positive initial state $f_0 \in L^1(\mathbb{R}^2).$
The problem is similar to the diffusion equation, for which, as is well known, there is a fundamental solution on the whole space.
The equation can also be written as:
$$ \partial_t f = \frac{1}{4} \partial_{x_1 x_1}^2f + \partial_{x_2 x_2}^2f + \left(\frac{1}{4}x_1 - 4x_2 \right) \partial_{x_1} f + \left(4x_1 + x_2 \right) \partial_{x_2} f + \frac{5}{4}f.$$
The (normalized) steady-state $f_{\infty}$, solution of the corresponding elliptic equation $$ 0 = {div} \left [\left( \begin{array}{rr}
    1/4 & 0  \\ 
    0 & 1  \\
    \end{array}\right) \nabla f + \left( \begin{array}{rr}
    1/4 & -4  \\ 
    4 & 1  \\
    \end{array}\right)xf \right ]$$ is known, it would be $$ f_{\infty}(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} {exp}\left(-\frac{1}{2}(x_1^2+x_2^2)\right).$$
Unfortunately I am not that very well versed in PDEs. So are there any results on explicit solutions of such equations on the whole space in 2D?
I strongly assume the solution should be very similar to one of the heat equation.

I would be very grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the linear PDE is just the PDF corresponding to $\mathcal{N}(\mu_t, \Sigma_t)$ where $$
\mu_t = \exp(A t) x \;, \quad \text{and} \quad \Sigma_t = 2 \int_0^t \exp(A (t-s) \begin{bmatrix} 1/4 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \exp(A^T (t-s)) ds
$$ where $A= -\begin{bmatrix} 1/4 & -4 \\ 4 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

This solution can be easily obtained by using the correspondence between SDE/PDE.  In particular, the corresponding SDE is  $$
d X_t = A X_t + \sqrt{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} d B_t
$$ where $B_t$ is a standard $2$-dimensional Brownian motion.  This SDE is a non-symmetric Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process due to the presence of a skew term in the drift, but since the SDE is linear, it can be explicitly solved to obtain the transition distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mu_t, \Sigma_t)$.  It is also straightforward to verify that $\mathcal{N}(\mu_t, \Sigma_t) \to \mathcal{N}(0,I_{2\times2})$ as $t \to \infty$.

Standard references for this are:

*Metafune, G.; Pallara, D.; Priola, E.*, [**Spectrum of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck operators in $L ^{p}$ spaces with respect to invariant measures**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jfan.2002.3978), J. Funct. Anal. 196, No. 1, 40-60 (2002). [ZBL1027.47036](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1027.47036).

*Pavliotis, Grigorios A.*, [**Stochastic processes and applications. Diffusion processes, the Fokker-Planck and Langevin equations**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4939-1323-7), Texts in Applied Mathematics 60. New York, NY: Springer (ISBN 978-1-4939-1322-0/hbk; 978-1-4939-1323-7/ebook). xiii, 339 p. (2014). [ZBL1318.60003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1318.60003).

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and helpful answer. The reference in particular will certainly help me further.